# On the not so clear relationship between torsion theories and localization for a newcomer

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories, abelian-categories

Given an hereditary torsion theory $(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{F})$ on an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, how we can relate this to a localization (i.e Ore localization). This is mentioned with not so much detail or with a lot of encyclopedic references (hard to follow), in a lot of books and papers concerning torsion theory. Still dont see how  given an hereditary torsion theory $(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{F})$ we can produce a subclass of morphism $W \subset \mathcal{A}$ such that there is a pair $(T, C_{W})$ where $T:C \to C_{W}$ is a universal functor and $C_{W}$ is at least an additive category. And where $T(w)$ is and isomorphism in $C_{W}$ for each morphism $w \in W$.  Also, viceversa, given a localization like mentioned before...How we can produce a torsion theory?

Also when $T$ is a triangulated torsion and $(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{F})$ is an hereditary torsion in a triangulated category how can we produce a localization of $T$ over subclass of morphisms $W \subset Mor(T)$ like the one mentioned before and $T_{W}$ preserves the triangulated structure of $T$. The same doubt for the converse process.

Comment: The go-to reference for this kind of stuff, in general categories (but largely specialised to the additive/abelian setting) is Cassidy, Hébert and Kelly's [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/reflective-subcategories-localizations-and-factorizationa-systems/0DDCB060FE9EB733D5B2EE94B0DAEF4C). I had a good understanding of this stuff at the times. Feel free to ask more specific questions!

Comment: @fosco Thanks so so much for your article recommendation. I'm checking it out and I want to follow the last part when he establish a bijection on an abelian category between their hereditary torsion theories and localizations. I follow her definition of an (hereditary) torsion theory but Its not so clear(at least for me) what he understands as a localization. How his definition of a localization is the same like this one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_category

Comment: @fosco Its my belief they are understanding a localization as some sort of reflection or adjunction, right?

Comment: Yes. A thorough introduction to localisation of categories and in particular to the special case of reflective localisations, is in the first tome of Borceux's *handbook*. It would take too much time to expand :-)